# login with two different users for different use in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How can generate following scenario,

1. user1 logged in & take some action on form.
2. user2 logged in & approve the taken action.

please suggest best way to automate the scenario via jmeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve:

1. Easy way: single [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). Just add one [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler per each action, i.e.:

   - HTTP Request 1 - login 1st user
   - HTTP Request 2 - perform an action
   - HTTP Request 3 - logout 1st user
   - HTTP Request 4 - login 2nd user
   - HTTP Request 5 - approve the action
   - etc.
2. If you have 2 Thread Groups, i.e. first one is creating the actions and the other one is approving them the best option to ensure that the the "approvers" have something to approve will be using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin, this way you will be able to "pause" the approvers until approval forms get created. You can install Inter-Thread Communication plugin (as well as the other plugins) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Inter Thread Communication]